# Soap film retraction dynamics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, viscosity

Let’s say you have a planar soap film, which thickness increases linearly. If you burst it, the film will retrace and the retracing speed will decrease. How exactly does the velocity of bursting depend on the film thickness? I need to find the equation describing this kind of retraction.